# is there any request limit for GeoLite2 free databases? (Hive UDF)

Tags: hive, geoip, hive-udf, freegeoip

I've downloaded free geoiplite databases from [link](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/geolite2/).
I am going to use it in [hive-geo-ip-udf](https://github.com/Spuul/hive-udfs).

Update:

```
SELECT geoip(host,'COUNTRY_CODE','/home/dhruv/GeoLite2-Country.mmdb') 
from table_name;
```

For 64th entry i am getting `FAILED: UnsupportedOperationException null`.

Comment: I don't think so, unless they think you're abusing it (they have some detection techniques AFAIK). I have been using it for a long time with high-amount of requests but never had a problem.

Comment: I've 30k+ ips in my hive table. when i try to execute it it successfully execute upto 63 rows.

Comment: When i try to execute it for particular 64th entry only then it gives
FAILED: UnsupportedOperationException null

Comment: I don't think its because of the the limits, could you update your post to show how you use it? Also try to send 63 request every second or two, to check it if its limiting you.

Comment: May be library unable to find location for that ip. So it breaks further execution.  See updated question.

Answer (score 0):

There was bug in library. It throws exception in case it didn't not find any location for ip. It was fixed now by returning empty string.

https://github.com/Spuul/hive-udfs/issues/2